# I cannot create a connection for ef-code first with oracle 11g

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, ef-code-first

How can I do to create a connection for code first with Oracle? I do not a reputation enough to post image. In my provider list I have no provider for Oracle, but I add reference Oracle Client on my project and I create a connection on Servers Explorer and is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework connection strings are not the same as normal database conenction connections strings. Please take a look at: [MSDN Connection String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/cc716756(v=vs.100).aspx).

Also provide us some more code / information.

Also take a look at: [Configuring for Entity Framework Code First](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56485_01/win.121/e55744/InstallEntityConfig.htm#ODPNT8266)